# Determining video extension in Perl when file has tmp extension

Tags: perl

I am performing a video upload using `perl` and I want to **determine the video extension** when for example the path is like `1lmZeK7M.1`.

As you can see, the path has `.1` at the end instead the file extension for a video.

How do I get the file extension for a video in Perl with a file name like above?

Comment: One general way is to invoke another program, like the `file`command or `ffmpeg` with the right options or `mediainfo`, and parse the results.  So it would depend on what tools you have available.  In fact `mediainfo` can make XML output, so that could be very nice with perl

Comment: Or be lazy and get the mediainfo module from CPAN to do it for you.  :)  https://metacpan.org/pod/Mediainfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, you'll have to look at the file itself.

The module [File::LibMagic](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/File-LibMagic-1.15/lib/File/LibMagic.pm) provides binding for the `libmagic` library. From documentation

```
use File::LibMagic;

my $magic = File::LibMagic->new();
my $info = $magic->info_from_filename('path/to/file');

print $info->{description};  # description, like "ASCII text"
print $info->{mime_type};    # MIME type,   like "text/plain"
```

However, the library `libmagic` itself may not be installed.

Another module that may help is [File::Properties](http://search.cpan.org/~wohl/File-Properties-0.02/lib/File/Properties.pm), geared toward media files.

Finally, if hurdles with compiling modules are too great we can reach for system utilities

```
my $info = `file $file`;
```

Then parse output for video-related phrases. Or, perhaps use `file`'s option `--mime-type`.

On the file `unknown`, which I copied form a good `.png` file

```
> file --mime-type unknown
```

returns the line `unkown: image/png`.  The extension is extracted from here by, for example,

```
my $info = `file --mime-type $filename`;

my ($name, $type, $ext) = $info =~ m| ([^:]+) : \s* ([^/]+) / (.*) |x;
```

The `/x` allows spaces for readability. The *negated character class* `[^:]+` captures everything other than `:`, so all up to first `:`. Then `[^/]+` takes all up to first `/`.

PLease test `file` on all of your expected video formats to see exact output.

Comment: This looks great. Can you add the parsing code against mp4? I'm very new to perl. I tried looking here (http://computer-programming-forum.com/53-perl/58bc9d6e94687bd3.htm) with no real answer

Comment: @jkushner  I added to the post.  But you'll have to try with `find` on your system and your files to see its exact output.  It should be exactly like the example I use though.

Comment: im looking to parse the output of the file command which i think is what you meant instead of find command. so for example, if(output has mp4) than we know its an mp4. if(output has avi) than we know its avi

Comment: @jkushner Oh, sorry ... correcting ... fixed. Thank you!  Yes, that's how you can do it.  Once you have `$ext`, you can do `if ($ext eq 'mp4') { ... } elsif ($ext eq 'avi') { ... } ...`.  There are nicer ways to make that selection, but this is simple and clear.